# react-native-image-crop-picker Video upload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-navigation

I'm using  `react-native-image-crop-picker` in my project. I have successfully uploaded images to server but when I tried to upload Video file's, It starts giving network error.
Whats the possible way to handle this?